# What properties does the vacuum have?

Tags: vacuum

Once upon a time the vacuum was defined as "nothing". We now know it has all kinds of properties such as permeability, dimensionality etc. Is there a list of such properties anywhere?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. "The vacuum" doesn't exist. When you speak of "permeability" (probably having $\epsilon_0$ in mind), it seems you are asking for the classical vacuum. In contrast, each quantum field theory has their own, possibly degenerate notion of vacuum state, and there you do not associate such things as "permeability" to it, but rather define it by its behaviour under annihilation operators. Also, what do you mean with "dimensionality"?

Comment: You remind me of my days working in X ray tubes. If there was a leak in one of the devices, the technician used to say that "the vacuum leaks out". :-)

Comment: So people who measure permeability of the vacuum, and those who report the values in scientific literature and just talking bollocks?